# Centered logo in navigation bar

Tags: css, html, nav

Ok so I have made this naviagtion bar:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/Mgurej6L

CSS: http://pastebin.com/vA7b1dT6

I would like "Unity Code" in the middle of my navigation bar but I've tried but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

Comment: Your question is unclear!
Nowhere in your code do you have "Unity Code" , except for the title of the page itself. So what do you exactly mean?

And more importantly, please add your code here on Stack Overflow with the editor (code) so that the question & answer can become useful for everyone here. 
I'd like to help you on this, but you need to ask your question more clearly including the code here.

Comment: I have add the code below in the answer I hope that will help who read the question and that what you asking for. if he didn't edit the question we can edit it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, in order to make your **navigation** in the **center of the page** you need to **rope** your **navigation** in the **div** so I add **div** with **class** `.rope` and you style `.rope` `{ display: flex; justify-content: center;}` like in code below:

```css
/*Css Navigation code*/

.rope {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.unity-code-logo {
  background-size: 100px 59px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 59px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 460px;
}
.main-navigation {
  display: inline;
  font-family: ubuntu;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
  color: #fff;
  background: #181818;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-navigation li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.main-navigation li:hover {
  @include transition(background, 0.25s);
  background: #453E3E;
}
.main-navigation ul li ul {
  background: #181818;
  visibility: hidden;
  float: left;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: visibility 0.65s ease-in;
  margin-top: 12px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
.main-navigation ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-navigationul li ul li:hover {
  background: #74b7e4;
}
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="rope">
  <!--Navigation Bar-->
  <nav id="navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation-menu-main">
      <li><a href="#" class="navigation-menu-main-item">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navigation-menu-main-item">Store</a>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://mt.google.com/vt/icon?color=ff004C13&name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-b.png" style="height:10px;"></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navigation-menu-main-item">Projects</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="navigation-menu-main-item sub-navigation-menu">Connect</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="navigation-menu-main-item sub-navigation-menu">Alpha</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="navigation-menu-main-item sub-navigation-menu">XXXX</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="navigation-menu-main-item sub-navigation-menu">XXXX</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

> Also `div(.rope)` by **default** is **100% width** so if you want to
>   give **width** to **rope div** you need to add `margin: 0 auto;`to
>   `(.rope)` in the style.
>   Just Add `<img>` in another `<li></li>` but because you don't have but 3 so is not going to be in the middle it could be right or left otherwise is going to be with the middle `<li></li>` for the store below the word.

Let me know is that what you need?